# Lazily Evaluate Insert Arguments If Constraint Violated

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, insert, constraint

```sql
create table a (
    b text not null unique,
    c text not null
);

-- Sleeps for 1 second as expected.
insert into a (b, c) values ('d', pg_sleep(1)); 

-- Sleeps for 1 second even though record is not inserted.
insert into a (b, c) values ('d', pg_sleep(1));
```

Is there anyway to restructure the second statement such that the `pg_sleep` (or actual intensive function I am calling) is run only if no constraint is violated based on `b`? Note that `c`(the result of the function call) has no bearing on the constraint.

Couple workarounds:

1. `insert` with only `b`, and `update` `c` in the next statement if the `insert` occurred with no error. The downside is that I have to loosen / remove the `not null` constraint of `c`, since it will be temporarily null.
2. Under an advisory lock, check if an `a` with same `b` already exists, and if not do the `insert`. The downside is that I replicate the uniqueness check manually, and have negative performance implications.

Comment: #2 seems the best option: if there is correct indexing then the performance will be almost the same.

Comment: With the `UNIQUE` constraint in place, the perfect index is provided implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the check in the same query, the expensive function call is only executed if there is no conflicting row, yet:

```
INSERT INTO a (b, c)
SELECT 'd', pg_sleep(1)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM a WHERE b = 'd');
```

Now, the insert ***can*** still fail under concurrent write load. Postgres does not allow to lock hypothetical rows. (So I don't see how an advisory lock would help.) But that only happens if a concurrent transaction happens to insert the same value for `b` concurrently and should be extremely rare. You only lose the performance optimization in that case, and nothing breaks.